# Parse string containing literal with Boost Spirit Qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I would love to parse a string like this:

```
<stuff I don't care> <literal value> <more stuff I don't care>
```

with `boost::spirit::qi`. Let's assume that `<literal value>` is e.g. `ABC`, then I would like the parser to accept:

```
Some text ABC more text
```

but reject:

```
Some text ACB more text
```

Unfortunately,

```
*char_ >> lit("ABC") >> *char_
```

does not work due to qi's greediness. Is there an easy way to write this parser?

Comment: Doesn't `*(char_ - lit("ABC")) >> lit("ABC") >> *char_` work?

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the right-hand side parser of the minus operator must parse a subset of the parser at the left side.

Comment: I'll make this an answer then ;). I just wasn't sure, since it's been quite a while since I worked with Boost.Spirit (in particular before it was named Qi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
*(char_ - lit("ABC")) >> lit("ABC") >> *char_;
```

instead to prevent `char_` from consuming `"ABC"`.